Python Tkinter Row Stacking Animation
I want to make an animation where a row of objects moves down the screen until they reach a specified row and then generate the next row that moves down from the same starting position and stops a row above the previous row. So it behaves like a stacking animation in a slot machine. How could I do this? With my current code, all the rows are stopping at the bottom and overlapping each other.
Code:
class SpinSlot:
    def __init__(self, new, grid):
        self.new = new
        self.grid = grid

    def spin(self):
        self.drop_row(0)

    def drop_row(self, row):
        if row < 7:
            for c in range(7):
                # Create a dropping effect by placing images row by row
                randomNum = random.randint(1, 490000)
                for key in image_mapping.keys():
                    if randomNum in key:
                        file = image_mapping[key]
                        break
                # Initially place the image off-screen
                self.grid.place_object(row=row, col=c, obj_type="image", image_file=file, offset_y=-100)

            # Move the row down step by step
            self.move_row_down(row, -100)

    def move_row_down(self, row, current_offset):
        # Calculate the target position for the row
        final_pos = self.grid.cell_size * (6 - row)  # Each row stacks above the previous one
        step_size = 10
        if current_offset < final_pos:
            for c in range(7):
                # Move each image in the row down by one step
                self.grid.move_object(row=row, col=c, offset_y=current_offset + step_size)

            # Schedule the next step
            self.new.after(50, lambda: self.move_row_down(row, current_offset + step_size))
        else:
            # Ensure the row stops exactly at its final position
            for c in range(7):
                self.grid.move_object(row=row, col=c, offset_y=final_pos)
            # Drop the next row after a short delay
            self.new.after(100, lambda: self.drop_row(row + 1))

class GridWrapper:
    def __init__(self, canvas, rows, columns, cell_size, images_ref):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.cell_size = cell_size
        self.images_ref = images_ref
        self.create_grid()

    def create_grid(self):
        # Draw vertical lines
        for col in range(0, self.columns):
            x = col * self.cell_size
            line = self.canvas.create_line(x, 0, x, self.rows * self.cell_size, fill="black")
            self.grid_lines.append(line)

    def clear_grid(self):
        # Clear all objects from the canvas
        self.canvas.delete("all")
        self.images_ref.clear()

    def place_object(self, row, col, obj_type="image", image_file=None, offset_y=0):
        global images_ref

        # Calculate the top-left corner of the grid cell
        x1 = col * self.cell_size
        y1 = offset_y
        x_center = x1 + self.cell_size // 2
        y_center = y1 + self.cell_size // 2

        if obj_type == "image" and image_file:
            img = Image.open(image_file)
            img = img.resize((self.cell_size - 10, self.cell_size - 20), Image.LANCZOS)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            item_id = self.canvas.create_image(x_center, y_center, image=photo)
            images_ref[(row, col)] = (photo, item_id)  # Prevent garbage collection

    def move_object(self, row, col, offset_y):
        global images_ref
        photo, item_id = images_ref[(row, col)]

        x1 = col * self.cell_size
        y1 = offset_y  # Adjust y1 based on offset_y for smoother animation
        x_center = x1 + self.cell_size // 2
        y_center = y1 + self.cell_size // 2

        self.canvas.coords(item_id, x_center, y_center)

I tried changing the offset and starting with a set current_offset but nothing is working.
